# How to get vim to work with tmux properly?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm trying to figure out how to get `vim` and `tmux` play together.

My problem is:
When I use `xterm-256color` I get `vim` to work nicely, but the background doesn't render properly.

I fixed this by using `screen-256color`. This looks nice but breaks the `Ctrl + arrow keys` (they go in insert mode and delete 4 lines). I want to use these mappings instead to switch tabs in `vim`.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `cat` within `tmux` and press the keys in question to find out the escape codes they generate. For me this gives `^[[D` and `^[[C`. Then just map those escape codes directly.

```
nnoremap ^[[D gT
nnoremap ^[[C gt
```

where the `^[` is an escape character, that you can insert by pressing `<CTRL-v><ESC>` in vim.

Comment: That didn't change the behaviour of my vim.

Comment: What's printed when you start cat within tmux and press the keys?

Comment: ^[[1;5C and ^[[1;5D. Good idea, I didn't know how to get those. Just tried it. It works! Thank you.

Comment: Great. I edited my ansewer to incorporate the method to get the right escape codes.

Answer (score 24):

There are several levels of configuration that need to be set up correctly for the best functionality.

1. Configure *tmux* to recognize the sequences. Before launching *tmux*, set a TERM value that is appropriate for your terminal emulator (e.g. `xterm-256color`). The terminfo database entry identified by the TERM environment variable tells *tmux* how to recognize the sequences for the modified arrow keys (the user-defined capabilities {`kUP`,`kDN`,`kRIT`,`kLFT`}{,`3`..`7`}).
2. Configure *tmux* to generate the sequences. Set the `xterm-keys` session option to `on` so that *tmux* will generate its own xterm-style sequence when it receives a sequence that its TERM identifies. In your `~/.tmux.conf`:

   ```
   set-option -g xterm-keys on
   ```
3. Configure the programs running inside *tmux* to use/expect the majority of its sequences. Make sure you are using a `screen`-based TERM inside *tmux* (e.g. `screen-256color`). This tells programs running inside *tmux* how to control *tmux*’s terminal (re)emulation and what responses they should expect from *tmux*.
4. Unfortunately, `screen`-based terminfo database entries often do not define any sequences for the modified arrow keys (i.e. they may not have `kUP`, et cetera), so the programs running inside *tmux* may not know to expect such sequences. You will need to manually configure any programs that you want to recognize these keys. In *Vim*, you can put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   if &term =~ '^screen'
       " tmux will send xterm-style keys when xterm-keys is on
       execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
       execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
       execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
       execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
   endif
   ```

   You may want to use the variants without `x` (i.e. `<Up>` instead of `<xUp>`, et cetera) if you find that using the `x`-variant causes your normal arrow keys to stop working.

   The advantage of defining the keys like this is that you do not have to map each of the modifier combinations separately (Shift, Control, Contol+Shift, Meta, Meta+Shift, Meta+Control, Meta+Control+Shift); the `*` gets special interpretation to handle all the related sequences (see `:help xterm-modifier-keys`).
5. Then you can map the keys instead of their hard-coded sequences:

   ```
   nnoremap <C-Right> gt
   nnoremap <C-Left> gT
   ```

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

[As explained here](http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html), disable **Background Color Erase** (BCE) by clearing the `t_ut` terminal option (run `:set t_ut=` in Vim and then press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the terminal's display) so that color schemes work properly when Vim is used inside tmux and GNU screen.

This way, you can keep your `TERM` value as `xterm-256color` for proper key detection while also getting proper Vim color scheme rendering too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does setting `set t_Co=256` in your ~/.vimrc help at all?  This is just a colour setting but may help clear some problems.

You could re-map the `ctrl+Arrow` keys in your ~/.vimrc as well...

Edit: did you try `ctrl+Arrow` in a GNU screen session?  I think this maybe your problem.

Comment: it looks and works fine in screen with xterm-256color

Comment: set t_Co=256 is done aswell

Comment: Did any of it help?

Comment: unfortunately no. What do you exactly mean with remapign ctrl+arrow? I use them already remapped to switch tabs in vim.

Comment: its mapped like this: map <C-Right> gt

Comment: Ah, so clearly something else (either your terminal or screen) is grabbing those before they get to vim.  I would look there but sadly I am not familiar with tmux.  Sorry.

Comment: I think the keycomboes map to different internal commandos in xterm and screen but im no expert either.