# tmux option `xterm-keys` does not enable control+arrows

Tags: tmux, inputrc

I cannot make tmux recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left-arrow</kbd> sequence differently from just a left arrow, and the same for the right arrow too. In my `~/.inputrc`, I have mapped these sequences (as issued by 2 different terminal emulators, namely putty and mobaxterm) to jump over words in command line:

```
"\eOD": backward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
```

This works in an ssh session just fine, but both screen and tmux do not distinguish between arrows and control-arrows. Naturally, [the recommended solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34723/103076) is to enable the option xterm-keys in tmux by adding the global option into `~/.tmux.conf`, and there is [direct evidence](https://superuser.com/questions/882840/tmux-screen-ctrlarrow-left-right-doesnt-work-on-ssh) (besides the "thanks" comments to the above solution) that this works for other people. But for me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left-arrow</kbd> sends the same code, `ESC D`, as does <kbd>Left-arrow</kbd>.

I have confirmed that the option is indeed set by checking tmux options with

```
:show-window-options -g
```

and even set it just in case for the current window manually with

```
:set-window-option xterm-keys on
```

but all this to no avail. tmux reports version number 1.8 with `tmux -V`.

What else may I check to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `-g` (global) option in this line:

```
:set-window-option xterm-keys on
```

making it

```
:set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

for tmux 1.8.  However, tmux 3.3 enables this feature by default (changed [May 2020](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/5ee4d991b6a325848083017665ac3d3ace2d1fa1), released [June 2022](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/ced83792b1b2c982f967ae7f6938fa0bbda12353)):

```
commit 5ee4d991b6a325848083017665ac3d3ace2d1fa1                                 
Author: Nicholas Marriott <nicholas.marriott@gmail.com>                         
Date:   Fri May 15 10:31:54 2020 +0100

    xterm-keys has been on by default for 5 years and all other modern terminals
    use these key sequences by default. Merge the code into the main tty and input
    tree processing (convering the latter to use a tree rather than a table at the
    same time) and make the option a no-op.
```

The [`tmux` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) is not very clear, saying of `-g`:

> If **`-g`** is specified, the *global session* or *window* option is set.
> With **`-a`**, and if the option expects a string, *value* is appended to
> the existing setting.  The **`-u`** flag unsets an option, so a session
> inherits the option from the *global* options.  It is not possible
> to unset a *global* option.

The key part of this is *session*, which is the set of pseudo-terminals create when you *start* `tmux`.

Comment: Better later than never. Sorry, forgot to tick your answer green 5 years ago! :)

Comment: xterm-keys is a no-op now. Looks like that behavior is just the default. https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/5ee4d991b6a325848083017665ac3d3ace2d1fa1